# How to use laser_scan_matcher with depthimage_to_laserscan and gmapping?

Tags: slam, navigation, asus-xtion-pro-live, gmapping, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am kinda new to ROS here, so please help me out accordingly.
I am using ROS Indigo on a Ubuntu 14.04 system. I am using an Asus XTion Pro Live to record a bag file of the `/scan` topic that I am getting from `depthimage_to_laserscan` node. I can view the scan properly in rviz and also through `rosbag play`.
Now, the issue is that I want to use `gmapping` to perform some basic SLAM but I don't have an `/odom` topic. So I thought of using `laser_scan_matcher` to get the `Pose2D` from my "fake" laser scans.
I tried out the demo given [here](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher) and it worked perfectly. However, when I try it with my own bag file, I don't get any output in rviz.
How can I use `laser_scan matcher` output with `rviz`?

---

**EDIT:**  
Here is what I'm doing so far  
 1. `roscore`
 2. `roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch`
 3. `rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw`
 4. `rosrun laser_scan_matcher laser_scan_matcher_node`

Here is the error I get from `laser_scan_matcher`

`Could not get initial transform from base to laser frame, "base_link" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.`
`Skipping scan`

Here is my `rqt_graph`
[image: rqt_graph image]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205845/how-to-use-laser_scan_matcher-with-depthimage_to_laserscan-and-gmapping?/) by [Nightstalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/20256/nightstalker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, got it working. There was an issue with the `tf` tree being published to `laser_scan_matcher`.
Here's my working launch file for `laser_scan_matcher`.
Just replace step 4 with `roslaunch <this_launch_file>.launch`

```
<launch>

#### publish an example base_link -> laser transform ###########
### this was the error ###
<!--node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 40" /-->
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 /base_link /camera_link 100"/>

#### start the laser scan_matcher ##############################
<node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">

    <param name="fixed_frame" value = "odom"/>
    <param name="base_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="fixed_frame" value="world"/>
    <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_odom" value="false"/>
    <param name="use_imu" value="false"/>
    <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>
    <param name="publish_pose" value="true"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_vel" value="false"/>

</node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [Nightstalker](https://answers.ros.org/users/20256/nightstalker/) with karma: 35 on 2015-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bsk](https://answers.ros.org/users/26601/bsk/) on 2016-06-09**:
so how can you see output in rviz? beside this launch file what did you write to see output in rviz?